# Which observation space to use from gym for a 3D Tensor matrix?

Tags: python, pytorch, environment, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am new to the field and I have developed my Env initislly without using gym. Now I intend to use stable baseline3 for PPO , so it uses the gym functionality.

The size of the state space currently is tensor of state - ( 1 x 4 x 17). Which space should I use from the gym ?

Also for the action space currently, the structure is like below:

```
decision_rule_stageI = {
            0: "SPT",
            1: "LPT",
            2: "SRM",
            3: "LRM",
            4: "Do nothing"
        }

        decision_rule_stageII = {
            0: "SPT",
            1: "LPT",
            2: "SRM",
            3: "LRM",
            4: "MFT",
            5: "MRT",
            6: "Do nothing"
        }

        decision_rule_stageIII = {
            0: "SPT",
            1: "LPT",
            2: "MFT",
            3: "MRT",
            4: "Do nothing"
        }
```

What kind of space should i use from gym ?

I tried looking at the documentation of Gymnasium , but still struggling to find out the correct information.